# Why does "拒不" mean "to refuse to do something"?

Tags: vocabulary, word

http://adm21.cmu.edu.tw/news_detail.php?sn=1572 :

```
不聽勸告即請其出場，該科成績以零分計；拒不出場，情節重大者，取消其考試資格，並報請有關機關處理。
```

http://ssdo.gov.taipei/ct.asp?xItem=6344506&ctNode=46432&mp=124011 :

```
如拒不參加全民健康保險，是否會受到處罰？
```

In the above examples, I can see that "拒不" means "to refuse to do something".

However, if I look at the words individually,
拒 = refuse
不 = not
If one uses "拒不", shouldn't it be a double negative, i.e. refuse not to do something?  If it is just to emphasize the meaning, wouldn't “堅拒” be a better choice?

Comment: 「拒不...」是「拒絕而不...」的意思。也就是「拒絕配合或遵守某項規定或處罰，而不...」。refuse to obey the rules and don't do something

Comment: 拒不 is choice 3 of Chinese IME, is not in "现代汉语词典＂１９９８年，but is _word_   in bkrs: refuse to do sth.她被通知交纳罚款，但她拒不服从。拒不交代
拒不出席会议
拒不悔改
拒不执行
拒不接受
拒不收纳
拒不改正
拒不服从
拒不服罪
拒不服输
拒不认付, example from rfa 拒不配合有关部门开展反恐怖主义安全防范、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [there are some teachers in school think the same as you do](http://www.guokr.com/question/608649/).

This also shows that there may be still debate in Chinese academia about how to explain this, so there might be not a definite answer.

Also, 拒不 [is still not considered a word](http://kns.cnki.net/KCMS/detail/detail.aspx?dbcode=CJFQ&dbname=CJFD2014&filename=HYXA201401010&v=MDUwNjdTN0RoMVQzcVRyV00xRnJDVVJMMmVaK1puRnk3aFdyM0tMVFRUYjdHNEg5WE1ybzlFWklSOGVYMUx1eFk=). But as it is used more and more frequently, it is becoming one.

[Another article on CNKI](http://kns.cnki.net/KCMS/detail/detail.aspx?dbcode=CJFQ&dbname=CJFD2014&filename=NXDX201403010&v=MTEzODdlWitabkZ5SGxVTC9JS3pYUGRyRzRIOVhNckk5RVpJUjhlWDFMdXhZUzdEaDFUM3FUcldNMUZyQ1VSTDI=) might shed some light on how to understand it, (but I cannot access the full article, only the abstract) which lists some similar phrases:

拒不VV
拒而不V
拒绝不VV

(a little hard to decipher the symbols in the abstract without the full article) The author seems to be claiming that it is two negative sentences "mixed" together.